# Change caption of toggle button

Tags: excel, vba

I have two toggle buttons, each on a different sheet.
The code of the toggle button is stored on the sheet level:

```
Private Sub MoveButton_Click()
    ClickToggleButton "move", ActiveSheet.Name
    'ToggleButtonPressed sSHEET2NAME
End Sub
```

The ClickToggleButton function is stored on the module level (because I want to use the same function for both buttons).

In my case while clicking one toggle button, the other button on the other sheet must be pressed, this works out well:

```
'switch button state to the same over the 2 sheets
Select Case sheetName
    Case sSHEET1NAME
        Worksheets(sSHEET2NAME).OLEObjects(sBUTTONMOVENAME).Object.Value = Worksheets(sSHEET1NAME).OLEObjects(sBUTTONMOVENAME).Object.Value
    Case sSHEET2NAME
        Worksheets(sSHEET1NAME).OLEObjects(sBUTTONMOVENAME).Object.Value = Worksheets(sSHEET2NAME).OLEObjects(sBUTTONMOVENAME).Object.Value
End Select
```

Now I only need to change the text (caption) on both buttons depending on the value you are in, I got error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method" on this line:

```
 Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).OLEObjects(sBUTTONMOVENAME).Caption = sButtonDescription
```

I guess it has to do with the fact where my code was stored ? I can change the value of the object but can't change the caption.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the caption of the button like you set the value - you need to use the `Object`-property of the OLEObject.

The OLEObject is just a wrapper around different kind of objects, while the `Object`-property is the button (or checkbox, or textbox or...) itself:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(sBUTTONMOVENAME).Object.Caption = sButtonDescription
```

You can also set other properties like Font, Color and the like:

```
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(sBUTTONMOVENAME).Objectws.OLEObjects(1).Object
    .Font.Size = 14
    .FontBold = True
    .FontName = "Broadway"
    .ForeColor = vbRed
    .BackColor = vbYellow
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, you're correct.
I had this code (while having only one toggle button) and it worked this way without the ".object" property when my code was on the sheet level. Thanks !